# Inline css background image not working

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

this is code i am using

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image: url('https://this is url/urlwebsite.com/images/sliderbg1.jpg');">
```

[image]

help me where is the problem

Comment: Where is your images folder exist?

Comment: Specify DIV element's height

Answer (score 0):

That image should appear .Here is the example

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/01-2014/7-flower-wallpaper.jpg)">
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/gLbn4dLm/

Edit: You have not specified Height of that DIV element. Please specify height of that DIV element.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `base_url()`

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image: url('<?php echo base_url() ;?>images/sliderbg1.jpg');">
```

> **Make sure your `images` folder is in root(Out side application Folder) of project.**